# ListView расстояние между Item

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Как можно задать расстояние между Items в ListView, дабы сгруппировать данные? 
По умолчанию расстояние равно размеру изображения

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: WinForms ListView

Comment: в ListView и ListViewItem нет свойств для изменения высоты отдельной строки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ListView и ListViewItem нет свойств для изменения высоты строк. Но возможно сделать следующее: включить отрисовку элементов, увеличить размер шрифта (высота элементов увеличится), а в обработчике DrawItem вывести текст нормального размера. Также можно выделить цветом элементы, относящиеся к одной группе.

```
#r "System.Windows.Forms"
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

var f = new Form() { Height = 370 };
var lv = new ListView {
    OwnerDraw = true,
    Font = new Font("verdana", 25),
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    View = View.Details,
    FullRowSelect = true,
    Parent = f,
    HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None
};
lv.Columns.Add("test");
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) lv.Items.Add(i.ToString());
lv.DrawItem += (s, e) => {
    var r = e.Bounds;
    r.Width = lv.ClientRectangle.Width - 5;
    if (e.ItemIndex % 3 == 0 || e.ItemIndex % 4 == 0)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.WhiteSmoke, r);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.Text, f.Font, Brushes.Black, r.Location);
};
lv.DrawSubItem += (s, e) => { };
lv.DrawColumnHeader += (s, e) => { };
f.ShowDialog();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]